# Java - Convert Twitter API 1.0 to 1.1

Tags: java, twitter

I never use twitter API 1.0 and I have given a task that I must change twitter API from 1.0 to API 1.1.

I don't use twitter4j.

What must I do ?

Comment: what is your *current* src code?

Comment: I try to make the application can be run because now twitter just use API 1.1, the application can't be run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are changes in the authentication model. [See this document](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview)